# Python getting user input and comparing input to string

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, user-input, led

I'm writing a program where the user can choose a color and have an LED of said color light up using a Raspberry Pi. After accepting user input and trying to compare it to a color, I get "NameError: name 'red' is not defined". How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

#use raspberry pi board numbers
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)  

#GPIO output channel
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(32, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(37, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(33, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)

#get led color
ledColorList = input("What color of light do you want to turn on? Red, green, blue, yellow, or all").split(' ')

#blink function
def blink(pin):
    GPIO.output(pin,1)
    time.sleep(.25)
    GPIO.output(pin,0)
    time.sleep(.25)
    return

if ledColorList[0] == RED:
    blink(7)  

#turn off all pins
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: This it's not a comparison of Strings : if ledColorList[0] == RED  don't forget the "" it should be something like:  if ledColorList[0] == "RED"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be a little better off forcing the input into lower case and taking it in through raw_input:

```
ledColorList = raw_input("What color of light do you want to turn on? Red, green, blue, yellow, or all").lower().split(' ')
```

then checking it against

```
if ledColorList[0] == "red":
    blink(7)
```

Comment: Thank you this makes it work as intended. Since I'm new to python could you explain if it was the going to upper case or the using input instead of raw_input that was making it fail?

Comment: Your question has "red" in lower case in the traceback, indicating that you had two problems:   1) there was no variable called "red", only one called "RED"     2) resolving this problem by using raw_input() would not resolve the case problem for string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

RED is a string litteral : it should be put between quotes.

Comment: I've fixed that and it runs now, but the light doesn't blink. Any idea why that would be?

Answer (score 0):

for python 2.x you can use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` because

> In Python 2.x, input() expects a Python expression, which means that if you type red it interprets that as a variable named red. If you typed "red", then it would be fine.